# How to access public folder in zf2 by htaccess subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, zend-framework2

I am new in zf2. Please help me.
I setup my new zend project on `www.example.com/zend/` directory
but it didn't call directly. Its call via `www.example.com/zend/public`

How can i access directly access by `www.example.com/zend/` this url. I don't want to any changes in virtual host. I want only use of `.htaccess` file.

Kindly suggest me solution.

Comment: @ReNiSh A R, please do *not* make such pointless edits where you change `xyz` to `example`... this does *not* improve this question *in any way*.

Comment: @Sheridan for demonstration and illustration we have to use the domain example.com. xyz.com is a website that owned by another. we dont have provinsion to use it...

Comment: @Sheridan: check: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120929/suggest-the-usage-of-example-com-for-examples-when-urls-are-encountered

Comment: @ReNiShAR, I accept your point and retract my statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup an htaccess file in your `/zend/` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /zend/
RewriteRule ^(?!public/)(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: thanks for reply. Its working but image not come means base path not set

Comment: @Rahul where are your images?

Comment: Thanks now working i include this code in module.config.php
'view_manager' => array(
    'base_path' => '/path/'
)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Apache web server. You can define virtual hosts only in .conf files, but not in .htaccess files.